# What is the difference between the Momento and Prototype Design Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, memento, prototype-pattern

Observed differences between the Momento and Prototype Design Pattern (from the GOF):

1. The Momento design pattern uses class x to create a snapshot of the internal state of class y. The Prototype design pattern uses class y to create a snapshot (=clone) of the internal state of class y.
2. The Momento design pattern is a behavioral pattern and the Prototype design pattern is a creational design pattern.
3. The Momento design pattern makes it possible to create a partial snapshot of the state of class y in class x. In the Prototype Design pattern a full snapshot (=clone) of class y is created.
4. Different in intent.

The same result can be achieved with both the Momento and Prototype Design Pattern:

- Prototype design pattern: the state of object x can be cloned, stored in a list, and assigned to object x in case an undo operation is required.
- Momento design pattern: the state of object x can be saved inside object y, stored in a list, and assigned to object x in case an undo operation is required.

What is the difference between the two patterns (besides the ones already listed)? When would we use one over the other? The Prototype pattern seems to me the preferred option, in case the full object needs to be 'snapshotted' and stacked in a list for an undo operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Prototype pattern describes a way in which objects are created. How the objects behave is irrelevant to the Prototype pattern. The Memento pattern describes a way in which objects behave. How the objects are created is irrelevant to the Memento pattern.

To state this more broadly, any creational pattern could produce the objects necessary for any behavioral (or structural or any other) pattern. This does not imply the creational patterns overlap in any way with whatever pattern(s) happen to be implemented by the objects they create.

The essence of a Memento is an object with two interfaces. From the GoF book page 285,

> Mementos have effectively two interfaces. Caretaker sees a *narrow* interface to the Memento—it can only pass the memento to other objects. Originator, in contrast, sees a *wide* interface, one that lets it access all the data...

So the key to the Memento pattern is in implementing these two interfaces in one object. If you choose to instantiate that object via cloning, you can employ two patterns; but there is a clear boundary between creation and behavior. The Prototype pattern stops once a clone is created. The Memento pattern starts when an object utilizes both a narrow and a wide interface.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it clarifies a lot. However if I look from a functional perspective it is hard to see the advantage of this narrow and wide interface. Let's pick an undo command example: imagine that we have an action and undo command. The action command 'stacks' the state of the receiver and performs some operation. The undo command pops an item from the stack and applies it to the receiver. Applying the Momento pattern, this would mean we save the Momento(s) in the stack. Using the Prototype pattern would mean we save the Originator(s) in the stack.

Comment: The only difference that I see here is that the Momento(s) in the stack have a more narrowed interface than if we would do the same with the Originators (prototypes). What is the advantage of doing so in this specific scenario?

Comment: I think the question is essentially, "Why should the `Originator` and the `Memento` be two separate classes?" The most obvious answer is #3 from the OP: _to create a partial snapshot_. But also to support the role of the `Caretaker`, which is to be, "responsible for the memento's safekeeping and never operate on or examine the contents of a memento." (p. 285) Exposing the full interface of the `Originator` through a `Memento` risks the state of the `Memento` changing after its creation.

Comment: thanks I understand now! The advantage of encapsulation in this case is safety, but also forcing the design in a correct direction. I.e. other developers are not capable of doing quick fixes by manipulating the Momento in the stack directly.